# Get test class name from which data provider method is called in TestNG

Tags: java, testng, factory, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider

I am using TestNG `@DataProvider` Annotation along with `@Factory` functionality in order to run a flow. When the control goes to `@DataProvider` method, I want to know from which test class this dataprovider method was called & on basis of that I want to supply test data.

This is my Bean class:

```
public class Bean {

    private String fName = null;
    private String lName = null;
    private String address = null;

    public synchronized String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public synchronized void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public synchronized String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public synchronized void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    public synchronized String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public synchronized void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

This is my constructor of TestClass with `@Factory`

```
@Factory(dataProvider = "dataProvider")
    public TestClass(Bean bean) {

        this.fName = bean.getfName();
        this.lName = bean.getlName();
        this.address = bean.getAddress();
    } 

Here is my DataProvider:

    @DataProvider(name = "dataProvider")
    public static Object[][] dataProvider() {
```

// Here I want to get the Test Class from which this DataProvider was invoked, so // with that I will supply the test data accordingly.

```
    Bean oneBean = new Bean();
        oneBean.setfName("Nisarg");
        oneBean.setlName("Dave");
        oneBean.setAddress("India");

        Bean secondBean = new Bean();
        secondBean.setfName("ABCD");
        secondBean.setlName("XYZ");
        secondBean.setAddress("UK");

        return new Object[][] { 
                                    new Object[] { oneBean },
                                    new Object[] { secondBean }
                              };
    }
```

Here in my DataProvider I know I can pass Method m or `ITestContext` as parameters, but both of them are not giving me Test class Name from which it was called.

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: PLease take time to visit this for better understanding: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/crambaqqnJc

Comment: The answer to the issue is: You just need to pass in an ITestNGMethod object as a parameter to your "@DataProvider" method. TestNG will natively inject a TestNG test method object into your data provider via which you should be able to extract out whatever you need.

Comment: Class clazz = method.getRealClass();

Method tm = method.getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();

Constructor constructor = method.getConstructorOrMethod().getConstructor();